# Java wrong data format transformation

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I need a Java program that subtracts 5 years from the current year.
Everything is working fine but after I run the program:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR,-5);
Date today = new Date();
String start = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()).toString();
String end = dateFormat.format(today).toString();
double start_doub = Double.parseDouble(start);
double end_doub = Double.parseDouble(end);
System.out.println(start_doub);
System.out.println(end_doub);
```

The result is:

```
2012.0
2017.0
```

I don't know the reason why the program adds `.0` after the year? 
How can I remove the last part?

Comment: Use `int` instead of `double`

Comment: How can a year be a double?

Comment: Okay, this was my mistake, after you suggested to use integer instead of double I know the reason. Thank you!

Comment: If you are using Java 8 or 9 this is much easier using the `Year` class from the new date/time support.

Comment: Don’t use strings to extract a year.  You already have a Calendar object.  Use `cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)` to get the year.

Comment: Use modern java.time classes instead. `Year.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ).minusYears( 5 )`

Comment: Even if you insist on using the old and outdated classes — which I strongly discourage — you are overcomplicating things. You just need a `Calendar`. You can still do without `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code look like below

```
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR,-5);
        Date today = new Date();
        String start = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()).toString();
        String end = dateFormat.format(today).toString();
        int start_doub = Integer.parseInt(start);
        int end_doub = Integer.parseInt(end);
        System.out.println(start_doub);
        System.out.println(end_doub);
```